# Piping a scalar to round function in r

Tags: r, dplyr, rounding

At the end of a long pipe I need to round a number to the nearest hundred. At the moment I'm trying this:

```
16036 %>% 
    round(./100)*100
```

I expect the function to return 16000 as is the case with:

```
round(16036/100)*100
```

How can I make the first expression work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

```
16036 %>%
    round(-2)
```

Answer (score 5):

Add curly brackets around the `round(. / 100)`. Currently the call resolves to `round(16036, 16036 / 100)`, but if you add the brackets, you don't pass the piped argument "again". (See e.g. http://magrittr.tidyverse.org/#re-using-the-placeholder-for-attributes)

```
16036 %>% {round(. / 100)} * 100
```

If you want to pipe the result further, you should include the multiplication in the curly brackets, due to operator precedence.

Comment: Ahh.. I was wondering how that was going to resolve... is there a way to see how pipe operations resolve explicitly?

Comment: Not that I know of, maybe that's one for the _magrittr_ authors?

Answer (score 4):

Here is an option with `magrittr` aliases

```
library(magrittr)
16036 %>%
     divide_by(100) %>% 
     round %>% 
     multiply_by(100)
#[1] 16000
```

---

Or another way is to make use of the `tidyverse` functions

```
16036 %>% 
  as_tibble %>%
  summarise(value = round(value/100)*100) %>% 
  pull(value)
#[1] 16000
```